# Send message to IRC channel from bash

Tags: ubuntu, bash, automation, irc

I have installed `ircd-hybrid` on my Ubuntu Server (192.168.1.2, example.com).
We use `#teamchannel` to communicate inside the team.

The question is: how can I send some short message from `example.com` to `#teamchannel` from the bash script? e.g. `example.com: Alert! The server is rebooting now`

### Edit:

I have found [a perl script](https://web.archive.org/web/20100125223219/http://www.javalinux.it/wordpress/2009/10/15/writing-an-irc-bot-for-svn-commit-notification/) which does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Link to perl script https://web.archive.org/web/20100125223219/http://www.javalinux.it/wordpress/2009/10/15/writing-an-irc-bot-for-svn-commit-notification/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use console irc client

```
apt-get install ii
ii -i /tmp -s 192.168.1.2
echo "/PRIVMSG #teamchannel example.com: Alert! The server is rebooting now" > /tmp/irc/in
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me. After `ii` the shell waits, when I end the command with `&`, the second command executes but without message.

Comment: red the 'out' file to debug problem: find irc directory(/tmp/SERVERNAME),cd /tmp/SERVERNAME and cat out,then echo message and read out.

Answer (score 12):

IRC is a simple text and line oriented protocol, so it can be done with the basic linux tools. So, without installing `ii`:

```
echo -e 'USER bot guest tolmoon tolsun\nNICK bot\nJOIN #channel\nPRIVMSG #channel :Ahoj lidi!\nQUIT\n' \
| nc irc.freenode.net 6667
```

In this command, `nc` does the network connection, and you send a login info, nick, join a channel named "#channel" amd send a message "Ahoj lidi!" to that channel. And quit the server.

Comment: add \nQUIT at the end of the list of commands to quit right after sending the one message

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use [expect](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065) to script communication with the IRC server using a telnet client.

Comment: Do I need `expect` when I want to send the message from the same machine where the IRC server is installed?

Comment: you do.. the above solution would work well with expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>/dev/tcp/example.com/6667
echo "NICK nickname1234" >&3
echo "USER nickname1234 8 * : nickname1234" >&3
echo "JOIN #teamchannel" >&3
echo "PRIVMSG #teamchannel Alert!" >&3
echo "QUIT" >&3
cat <&3
```

Comment: A bit of text around the shell script would go a long way to making this a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to supply a password and use ssl you can do something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

USER=$1
MYPASSWORD=$2
IRC_SERVER=$3
IRC_PORT=$4
CHANNEL=$5
MSG=$6

(
echo NICK $USER
echo USER $USER 8 * : $USER
sleep 1
echo PASS $USER:$MYPASSWORD
echo "JOIN $CHANNEL"
echo "PRIVMSG $CHANNEL" $MSG
echo QUIT
) | ncat --ssl $IRC_SERVER $IRC_PORT
```

The script should be run like this:

```
./post_to_irc.sh your_user your_pass irc_server 6667 "#target-channel" "Your message"
```

This is similar to an earlier example using `nc` but I found I had to use `ncat` to get it working with our IRC server which has been set up with SSL.